# Spring Integration: How to set up void outbound gateway methods

Tags: java, spring-integration, gateway

I'm having a problem setting up a channel for a void gateway message:

 
For now, I'm getting a exception 
`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available`

I have my outbound gateway setup like this:
`channel-> transformer-> channel-> outbound-gateway`
I didn't set a reply channel for the outbound-gateway, just a request channel

Question: What is the right way to set up outbound system request when you're not waiting for a response (except fault messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent any response is to use `<outbound-channel-adapter>` - **one-way** service-invoker. But I guess you use `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` and there is no `<outbound-channel-adapter>` on the matter.

In this case you can just `emulate` the same using `reply-channel="nullChannel"`.

It should be enough.